# What is the correct word for referring to the speaker of a song or poem?

Tags: poetry

Like "narrator", but for something that isn't a narrative. Do we have a word for that?

Comment: Perhaps a [performer](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/performer). You mention singing, and poetry that is read out loud (presumably for an audience) is sometimes called [performance poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_poetry).

Comment: In ancient times, it was a **bard** :  a composer, singer, or declaimer of epic or heroic verse

Comment: _Bard_ is no longer in general use, though it's the right archaic term. Nowadays I'd just say _singer_, whether they make what counts as music or not; just declaiming the poem any way at all is singing it. That's what the Greeks called it: _μῆνιν ἄειδε θεὰ Πηληϊάδεω Ἀχιλῆος οὐλομένην._ 'Sing, O Goddess, of the deadly wrath of Peleus's son Achilles'.

Answer (score 1):

**Speaker** or **voice** are probably the best terms, although you still see *narrator* used, and *persona* is sometimes an alternative. Note that some poems may have more than one speaker, for instance if they are dialogs. The speaker and voice, like the narrator of a narrative, are not necessarily the same as the poet.

The Academy of American Poets website says

> The speaker of a poem is the voice of the poem, similar to a narrator in fiction. The poet might not necessarily be the speaker of the poem. Sometimes the poet will write from a different perspective, or use the voice of a specific person, as in a persona poem. The term speaker clarifies the distinction from the poet’s perspective and the perspective they use in the poem.

A website from the University of Victoria in Canada suggests "all poems have a voice", as well as an "addressee", the person to whom the voice is implicitly speaking.

Both of these view a poem as conceptually something that is spoken by a person or person, so they may make slightly less sense in some forms, e.g. found poetry or other more experimental poetry. *Persona* would apply if the poet is speaking as somebody other than themselves.

- [Speaker](https://poets.org/glossary/speaker), Glossary of Poetic Terms, Academy of American Poets website, accessed 31 March 2023.
- [Speaker & Addressee; Narrative & Narrator](https://web.uvic.ca/hrd/closereading/speaker.html), *The Close Reading of Poetry: A Practical Introduction and Guide to Explication*, University of Victoria (Canada), accessed 31 March 2023

Comment: Some reference to aural language is necessary; poetry has to be uttered aloud. The sounds are the important part, and always have been. Poetry is millennia older than writing.